# Sending Database emails to multiple recipients while tweaking the body

Tags: sql-server

i need to send emails to approx, twenty recipients each day, i build a temp table with two columns

Email_Body
Email_address

there are at max 50 rows in the table each day

i want to loop though this table and execute sp_send_email

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
        @Profile_name = 'DBA',
        @recipients = @email_address,
        @body = @Email_Body,
        @subject = 'Test Email'
```

is there a way to do this without a cursor?

any links to an example would be appreciated, i have searched and can't find such an example. i am sure it is a very common process.

Answer (score 0):

You might try the solution found [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1207630.aspx/1).

Answer (score 0):

I think this code sample would help:

```
while (@count <=(select COUNT(*) from @table))
begin
select top 1 @Recepient_Email=Emp_Email,@mailBody=body from @table where ID=@count
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name='Profile1',
    @recipients=@Recepient_Email,            
    @subject = 'This is subject of test Email'
    @body = @mailbody,
    @body_format = 'HTML'
    set @count =@count +1
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
--Email Campaign.
declare @HtmlModel varchar(max)
declare @HtmlBody varchar(max)
SELECT @HtmlModel = EmailBody
FROM EmailCampaigns
WHERE ID = 1
--a different process will have created an awesome looking well formed html with our known
--placeholders for [FirstName] [LastName] [Phone] [Email] that might ber substituted for individualization
--PRINT @HtmlModel;
SET @HtmlBody=''



declare
    @mailID int,
    @id    int,
    @first varchar(64),
    @last  varchar(64),
    @phone varchar(64),
    @email varchar(64)

    declare c1 cursor for 
    --################################
    SELECT ID,
           ISNULL(FirstName,'Friend') AS FirstName, 
           ISNULL(LastName,'') AS LastName, 
           ISNULL(Phone,''),
           ISNULL(Email ,'')
           --the row_number is so that if i put your name in the database five times, you only get a single email.
    FROM (
          select ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by email order by email,len(firstname)desc,len(lastname)desc ) AS RW, * 
          from RawContacts
          where email <> '') x
    WHERE RW = 1
    --this WHERe stays in place until we are ready to go LIVE with the email.
      and email IN('lowell@somedomain.com','otherReviewer@somedomain.com')
    --################################
    open c1
    fetch next from c1 into @id,@first,@last,@phone,@email
    While @@fetch_status <> -1
      begin
        SET @HtmlBody = REPLACE(@HTMLModel,'[FirstName]',@first)
        SET @HtmlBody = REPLACE(@HtmlBody,'[LastName]',  @last)
        SET @HtmlBody = REPLACE(@HtmlBody,'[Phone]',     @phone)
        SET @HtmlBody = REPLACE(@HtmlBody,'[Email]',     @email)
        --EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
             @Profile_name = 'Database Mail Profile Name',
             @recipients=@email,
             @subject = 'Our non profits Call for Volunteers',
             @body = @HtmlBody,
             @body_format = 'HTML',
             @mailitem_id = @mailID OUTPUT
    --@body_format = 'TEXT'
        INSERT INTO CampaignRecipients(Campaign,RawContactID,MailSentID,MailSentDate)
          SELECT 1,@id,@mailID,GETDATE()
        fetch next from c1 into @id,@first,@last,@phone,@email
        end
    close c1
    deallocate c1


GO
```